# Trying to give less margin between my <h2> and <ul> elements

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have less space between my h2 and my ul elements.
But it seems that its not possible with margins, ul element seems not allow to have that margin.
Its necessary some trick to do this? Because Im trying with margins but its not working!

My html:

```
<div id="page">
   <div id="info">
              <h2>List 1</h2>  
                <ul>
                 <li><strong>List Item 1</strong> this is the content 1</li>    
                 <li><strong>List Item 2</strong> this is the content 2</li>     
                 <li><strong>List Item 3</strong> this is the content 3</li>   
              </ul>
              <h2>List 2</h2>
                 <ul>
                 <li><strong>List Item 1</strong> this is the content 1</li>    
                 <li><strong>List Item 2</strong> this is the content 2</li>     
                 <li><strong>List Item 3</strong> this is the content 3</li>   
              </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#page
{
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#page ul
{
    list-style:none; 
    background:pink;

}

#page ul li
{
    font-size:13px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-bottom:5px;


}

#page h2
{
    font-size:15px;
    color:#444;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background:green;
}


#info
{
    margin:10px 0 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: _“ul element seems not allow to have that margin”_ – that’s just wrong. Use your browser’s DOM inspector tools to find out where the unwanted spacing is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS Reset. This basically means resetting all your default paddings and margins and other basic attributes before applying your own styles.

Browsers will give tags a default margin, and it will vary between browsers, so you are best to just reset them yourself.

At the very least you should put something like this: `* {margin:0;padding:0}` at the top of your CSS.

[**See this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WDpMq/)

Look around and you can find a decent pre-made CSS reset. Here is a popular one made by [Eric Meyers](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/):

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Include this at the top of your CSS and you don't need to worry about the default browser styles getting in your way.

Comment: For my case, it only was necessary the body {line-height:1;}

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see (using only the code you provided), you are not taking into account the browser default settings. If you are not using Eric Meyers reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. In short, it sets all settings back to zero in all browsers for your site to have a starting point.

But if you do not want to use or cannot use this reset css file, You need to explicitly define settings. In your case, you need to add the following for each element and you will remove the gap you have currently:

```
#page ul
{
     list-style:none; 
     background:pink;
     margin-top: 0; /*override the default browser setting for the UL element*/
}
```

If you do not want any space at all between the H2 and the UL, change the margin-bottom on the H2 element to equal 0. I hope this is what you were looking for in your issue.